# see progress after reconnect through SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal

when i connect to a host (for example raspberry pi) through SSH , and execute some command like apt-get upgrade , i see this progress. but after interrupt , i can't see this progress. 
is there any way to see resume progresses , after reconnect ?

Comment: The command that you run remotely is very likely to be killed when the connection is interrupted. You should have a look at *screen* or *tmux*.